# Excel - Advanced Search with multiple Criteria - Account numbers using wildcard?

Tags: excel

I have a list of account numbers I want to be able to search using only parts of the string of numbers (I have tried them as numbers and as text).

I have 1 Sheet  with all the data, account numbers, names .ect, 1 sheet with criteria and 1 sheet (Interface) with the search boxes and output. I run an advanced search using a macro attached to a button that runs text in the search boxes through their respective criteria and spits out the filtered information. For example, for account name I use =IF(Interface!B11="","*",Interface!B11)for all of the text-based searches but can't get the account numbers to work.

Basically followed this tutorial but with my own data: https://www.onlinepclearning.com/excel-advanced-filter-multiple-criteria/

Comment: You can't use wildcards if your account numbers are stored as numbers rather than text.

Comment: I tried storing them as text as well and it still doesn't work

Comment: They need to be prefixed with an apostrophe. Simply formatting the cells as Text won't work.